# MethodNotAllowed on Skype for Business Channel

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I am running in to an error when trying to reach my bot over SfB. The dashboard shows "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code MethodNotAllowed" and SfB chat window shows "Error happened in Skype for business when reaching bot service"

The bot works fine on the web control, bot emulator and skype channel. I am running Bot.Builder 3.8.5 . I tried commenting out [BotAuthentication] but then every channel started to fail after that. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out an update to Bot.Builder was pushed out and took it to version 3.9.0.0 . After that re publish to Azure and it started working